# How to transfer a variable in java sampler to jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I wonder how can I transfer a variable in a java Sampler to jmeter variable, so the next test case which may be another kind of sampler can use this data come from other case.
resJson = JSONObject.parseObject(result);
resJson.get("responseCode")

I try to find a method in JavaSamplerContext to transfer variable from java sampler to jmeter variable, it do not exist.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JMeter 4.0, check out [JavaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html#getJMeterVariables--) function

1. Set a JMeter Variable:

   ```
    @Override
   public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
       context.getJMeterVariables().put("foo","bar")
   }
   ```
2. Get a JMeter Variable:

   ```
   @Override
   public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
       String foo = context.getJMeterVariables().get("foo");
   }
   ```

---

You might find using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) easier to use as it provides `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance. Well-behaved Groovy scripts have nearly the same performance as native Java code and you will not have to recompile the classes, update libraries in JMeter classpath and so on.